# Is it possible to embed animated GIFs in PDFs?

Tags: pdf, animated-gif

Is it possible to embed animated GIFs in PDFs? And how might I go about such a thing? are there any dangers I should be aware of?

For some more details on why I think it's a good thing and how it helps [feel free to see this post](https://joereddington.github.io/2014/04/18/animated.html). I didn't think it was appropriately well-formed enough for SE.

As an example - I'd like to put this into a description of quicksort:

[image: quicksort animation from wikipedia]

(This animation is from [wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sorting_quicksort_anim.gif).)

Comment: [It's possible if you generate a PDF with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5396/is-there-any-way-to-include-an-animated-gif-directly/5397#5397) but I think the gif is an external file

Comment: PDFs are really not just for "printing" only any more - they entirely replace the printed document with digital documents, so embedding animations would be a logical addition.  This is a great question, I don't see why it's not a widely supported/used feature.

Comment: (Don't forget to credit Wikipedia for this image.)

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55623) (and no other) works for me on a modern (2017) NixOS with Okular. Even autostart is supported in presentation mode (contrary to some places where it's stated that it's not).

Comment: Another solution is looking for epub.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I haven't tested it but apparently you can add quicktime animations to a pdf (no idea why). So the solution would be to export the animated gif to quicktime and add it to the pdf.

Here the solution that apparently works:

1. Open the GIF in Quicktime and save as MOV (Apparently it works with other formats too, you'll have to try it out).
2. Insert the MOV into the PDF (with Adobe InDesign (make sure to set Object> Interactive> film options > Embed in PDF) - It should work with Adobe Acrobat Pro DC too: [see link](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/rich-media.html)
3. Save the PDF.

See [this link](http://www.macuser.de/forum/f17/animierte-gifs-pdf-21509/) (German)

Comment: This is great!  But is there a free solution to do the same thing?  Adobe InDesign is >$300/year.  Also it's SO policy to actually copy the answer into the post - the translated page says to do the following: 1) Open the GIF in Quicktime and save as MOV (I could only get that to work with an AVI).  2) Insert the MOV into the PDF with Adobe InDesign (make sure to set `Object> Interactive> film options > Embed in PDF`  3) Save the PDF.

Comment: I can confirm that embedding a MOV file in a PDF via InDesign works. But Quicktime on my iMac refuses to open GIF files. Can you give more details about that part... what version of Quicktime are you using?

Comment: As well as MOV files, any multimedia that is H.264 compliant can be played in Adobe Reader 9 and later. That can include MPG and many other common formats. More here: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/rich-media.html

Comment: Including an mp4 in a PDF requires the Flash Player and will not be supported in most PDF readers. See this answer for more details: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/130211/3145

Comment: InDesign doesn't open or edit PDFs, so I'm not sure how to execute the instructions "Insert the MOV into the PDF with Adobe InDesign". When I try to open my PDF with InDesign I get an error "InDesign may not support the file format..."

Answer (score 54):

I do it for beamer presentations,

provide tmp-0.png through tmp-34.png

```
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{frame}{Torque Generating Mechanism}
  \animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{12}{output/tmp-}{0}{34}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: This worked great for me.  However, no Linux PDF reader I tried could view the animations.  I could only get them to work in Adobe Reader.

Comment: according to the documentation https://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate it works with Acrobat Reader, KDE Okular, PDF-XChange and Foxit Reader

Answer (score 18):

It's not really possible. You could, but if you're going to it would be useless without appropriate plugins. You'd be better using some other form. PDF's are used to have a consolidated output to printers and the screen, so animations won't work without other resources, and then it's not really a PDF.

Comment: Although it is true that GIF will not work "as is" inside a PDF, you can actually create animations using Javascript, but very few readers will support it.

Comment: PDFs may have been originally made for physical printing, but have now completely taken the place of printed documents - they are the de-facto digital document, so it makes perfect sense that we should allow them to embed animations.

Comment: @Demis, there is no we in PDF, only Adobe (the company)

Comment: @Nader that's actually a good point.  Adobe says PDF is an "open standard" by ISO - not sure just how "open: though.  https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/about-adobe-pdf.html   Also the site says PDF can contain video, maybe that's new.

Comment: @Demis, adding video to PDF's isn't that new ... and the only way in the past to add animated pics was by using (better said forcing) users to convert it to Flash ... Buy now that Adobe killed Flash, how the hell are we going to add animated Gif's and not videos !!!???

Comment: Since embedded video is supported, perhaps it would be possible to convert a GIF to a similarly small-sized video (indexed colors, small pixel size etc.)?

Answer (score 17):

You can use Tikz/pgfplots for creating animations in beamer. http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/animations/

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility is LaTeX + animate package. You will need to provide the individual frames making the animation. The resulting pdf does NOT require any plugin, the animation is shown in Adobe reader

Answer (score 8):

Maybe use LaTeX and try something like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\includemovie[
    poster,
    toolbar, 
    3Daac=60.000000, 3Droll=0.000000, 3Dc2c=0.000000 2.483000 0.000000,     3Droo=2.483000, 3Dcoo=0.000000 0.000000 0.000000,
    3Dlights=CAD,
]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}{Bob.u3d}
\end{document}
```

where Bob3d.u3d is a sample virtual reality file I had. This works (or did) for movies, and I expect it might work for gifs too.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to figure this out for a client presentation and found a work around to having the GIF play a few times by making a fake loop.

- Open the Gif in Photoshop
- View the timeline
- Select all the instances and duplicate them (I did it 10 times)
- Export as a MP4
- Open up your PDF and go to TOOLS> RICH MEDIA>ADD VIDEO> then place the video of your gif where you would want it
- A window comes up, be sure to click on SHOW ADVANCED OPTIONS
- Choose your file and right underneath select ENABLE WHEN CONTENT IS VISIBLE

Hope this helps.

Comment: Including an mp4 in a PDF requires the Flash Player and will not be supported in most PDF readers.

Comment: As an update, now that Adobe have already killed Flash, what is Adobe's solution for adding animated gifs ???

Answer (score 0):

As of acrobat pro version x, a gif can be added under **Tools > Insert from File**.  But the gif wont play, it only shows the first image.

Comment: For me the perfect solution is HTML.

Comment: @Jose, Good luck sharing that as attachment through corporate email with upper management kind of person.

Comment: That is no solution Jan

Comment: In other words, the answer is no?