# using .gif image in Active reports .i.e. in pdf it should display

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, gif, activereports, grapecity

I have a strange requirement , where the client wants a graphical logo which revolves to be printed on the reports. I am completely confused as on PDF can we display a .gif image. i gone through and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009771/is-it-possible-to-embed-animated-gifs-in-pdfs). So, generating reports by active reports9 is it possible. Need assistance guys. If its not we need to inform as early as possible to client. If it possible how. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying animated gif images in ActiveReports is not possible as of now. 
Gifs could be loaded inside the Picture control in reports as simple images but the animation part for them is not supported currently.

Comment: thanks @reema, i googled it a lot finally the answer was same as if now its not possible.