# How can we save jupyter notebook as pdf with a gif

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have an image of gif format in jupyter notebook. After I download the notebook as pdf, the gif disappear in the pdf. Any idea?

Comment: I think this thread might be a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009771/is-it-possible-to-embed-animated-gifs-in-pdfs